# How can I count when object walk pass a line with yolov5 (detect.py)?

Tags: python, yolov5

First I have my custom animal detection and I can detect it with yolov5 by run detect.py.
But I'd like to count it when animal walk pass a line like a picture as below.

[image]

I try to find solution and I met the [TensorFlow Object Counting API](https://github.com/ahmetozlu/tensorflow_object_counting_api) solution as a example picture .

Following this code.

```
# Imports
import tensorflow as tf

# Object detection imports
from utils import backbone
from api import object_counting_api

input_video = "./input_images_and_videos/pedestrian_survaillance.mp4"

# By default I use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the detection model zoo (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.
detection_graph, category_index = backbone.set_model('ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

is_color_recognition_enabled = False # set it to true for enabling the color prediction for the detected objects
roi = 385 # roi line position
deviation = 1 # the constant that represents the object counting area
custom_object_name = 'Pedestrian'
object_counting_api.cumulative_object_counting_x_axis(input_video, detection_graph, category_index, is_color_recognition_enabled, roi, deviation, custom_object_name) # counting all the objects
```

But this solution use SSD with Mobilenet.
I'd like to use it with my custom yolov5 (detect.py) and export Detect Pedestrians countable data to txt file.

Please supporting me If anyone can adaptation this Detect Pedestrians with yolov5.